# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file - Already googled

Tags: python

What is wrong with this error message? I googled for it and i still have no idea

> **ERROR MESSAGE**
>    Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Python Code Testing Bed\Function 6 - still in
>   progress.py", line 33, in 
>       writer.writerow([id_, name, combinedaddress, dateprinter, timeprinter, ', '.join(ingredients), totalprinter.group(1)])
>   ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import re

with open("rofl.csv", "rb") as f, open("out.csv", "wb") as out:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    writer.writerow(["Receipt ID","Name","Address","Date","Time","Items","Amount","Cost","Total"])
    groups = groupby(csv.reader(f), key=itemgetter(0))
    for k, v in groups:
        v = list(v)
        id_, name = v[0]
        add_date_1, add_date_2 = [x[1] for x in v[1:3]]
        combinedaddress = add_date_1+ " " +add_date_2
        dateplustime = [ x[1] for x in v[4:8] ]
        abcd = str(dateplustime)
        dateprinter = re.search('(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d)\s(\d\d:\d\d)', abcd).group(1)
        timeprinter = re.search('(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d)\s(\d\d:\d\d)', abcd).group(2)
        transaction = [ x[1] for x in v[8:] ]
        textwordfortransaction = str(transaction)

        INGREDIENT_RE = re.compile(r"^\d+\s+([A-Za-z ]+)\s")
        ingredients = []
        for string in textwordfortransaction:
            match = INGREDIENT_RE.match(string)
            if match:
                ingredients.append(match.groups())
                continue

totalprinter = re.search(r"\bTOTAL\b\s*(\d*).",textwordfortransaction)
writer.writerow([id_, name, combinedaddress, dateprinter, timeprinter, ', '.join(ingredients), totalprinter.group(1)])
```

Comment: just add 4 spaces before the last 2 lines.
here is good article about the `with` statement
http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is where you open the file:

```
with open("rofl.csv", "rb") as f, open("out.csv", "wb") as out:
```

The `with` block establishes the context. As soon as this context is left, the file will be closed. This:

```
writer.writerow([id_, name, combinedaddress, dateprinter, timeprinter, ', '.join(ingredients), totalprinter.group(1)])
```

…is outside the `with` block. The file has been closed by the time the program reaches this statement, because the `with` block has ended.

Indent the `write.writerow` to be within the `with` block.